# Can anyone explain why array.length would return two different results here?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please look at this:

```
(function ($) { 
    $.fn.extend({
        grid: function (settings) {
            var defaults = {
                data: [
                    ['Code','Name','Email','Other'],
                    [1,'John','john@domain.com','Johny'],
                    [2,'Bob','bob@domain.com','Bobby'],
                    [3,'Jenny','jenny@domain.com','Jen'],
                    [4,'Mary','mary@domain.com','Maryann']
                ],
                test: this.data.length
            };

            var config = $.extend(defaults, settings);

            return this.each(function(){
                this.innerHTML = config.data.length;
                this.innerHTML += "<br />" + config.test;
            });

        }
    });
}(jQuery));

$('.content').grid();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w8PG6/

And **explain why the two results are different?**

Also **how do I achieve the desired result?**

Comment: And just what is the desired result??

Comment: I would assume the desired result is 5 as that's the number of elements @Craig defines in 'data'

Comment: I would like to be able to use the correct array length for other variables within the defaults variable. So the desired result is to have them equal the same correct value. (5)

Comment: Aside from your problems with `this` that the 3 answers to date mention, currently your `test` property is saving the length of the array at that moment. What you want is a function that returns the length of the array at the time it is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you call `this.data.length`, it's actually counting the length of the jQuery [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data) function and not the length of `defaults`. Additionally, you can't count the length of `defaults.data` until after it's been assigned.

Have a look at this working example: http://jsfiddle.net/w8PG6/1/

Comment: Ah that makes a lot of sense and the example you provided is exactly what I was after. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at what `this.data` is when you're doing `this.data.length`. It's being evaluated based on the value of `this` in the `grid` anonymous function, which is `jQuery.fn`. So it's [`jQuery.fn.data`](http://api.jquery.com/data). Function.length is the arity of the function (the number of arguments), which is 2 (key, value).

Comment: No time now to elucidate on how to achieve what you want - but basically you'll need a function to evaluate it later on.

Answer (score 0):

`this` does not refer to your object under construction, but to whatever `this` is in the current context. In your case `this` just happens to have a property called `data`. Compare with:

```
var foo = {
    bar  : "bar",
    test : this.bar
}
```

This simply does not work. `foo.test` is `undefined`, unless there's a `var bar` in the same context. I don't think it's possible to assign both values in the same statement, since the array won't be assigned to anything that can be accessed until the assignment statement is done. The best you can do is:

```
var defaults = { data : [ ... ] };
defaults.test = defaults.data.length;
```

Comment: That's right assuming `defaults.test` is supposed to save the value of `data.length` at that moment. If the idea is to return the current length taking into account any modifications to the array then it should be a function.

Comment: @nnnnnn Instead of a function, you should just use `defaults.data.length` then... :)

Comment: Sure, and that's likely what I'd do in my code. Just wanted to be sure the OP understood the difference.